# How to make a variable equal another variable in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

@href currently holds content. I would like to overwrite it with @href_two.

I tried

```
<xsl:"@href"= "@href_two" />
```

But it didnt work

Comment: Do you actually mean "variables" here, or "attributes"? It would help a lot if you show a sample of your input XML, and the output you expect. It might be just a simple case of building on Identity Transform.

Comment: What on earth made you imagine that would work? You can't learn a programming language by trial and error. Take an evening to read a book. First principle: an XSLT stylesheet is an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

**Variables in XSLT are immutable.  Once set, they cannot be changed.**

If you say more about what your end goal is, we can explain how to achieve it without reassigning variables.  For example, counting can be achieved by matching positions against the input document, or through recursive invocation of functions with parameter values that change from one invocation to the next.